# Unable to save Jupyter notebook in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, save

I have been trying to save my jupyter notebook in the '.ipynb' format but am unable to do so, in whatsover extension. I encounter the following error message

```
Failed to save 'Untitled-1': File name file:///c%3A/Users/parni/OneDrive/Desktop/MINIPROJECT/INPUT/prac.py is not supported by Jupyter.

Please make sure the file name matches following patterns:
```

I am also not able to extend and check out what pattern should I follow it will be great if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely uninstalled VS code and It started working for .ipynb files. Followed the steps below. I have referred this solution from another thread of stackoverflow. I am not able to find the same hence adding answer below.

1. Uninstallation from Add remove program
2. Delete folder "C:\Users[user Name]\AppData\Roaming\Code".
3. Reinstalled VScode with all extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with VSCode.
To resolve this Press->
CTRL+SHIFT+P
and then JSON: Clear Schema Cache

Answer (score 2):

Goto File -> Save As, in "Save as Type" select **No Extension** and save the file with file name "name".ipynb

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In your VS code environment,

- search Jupyter in the Extensions
- uninstall Jupyter and re-install it
- You save the code without any changes.

Comment: Reinstalled and then selected "No extension" while saving worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - I believe it has to do with the update to VS Code notebooks.

I resolved it with the following steps:

- Open settings.json (CTRL + SHIFT + P --> Open Settings JSON)
- Change `"workbench.editorAssociations": {"*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"}` to `"workbench.editorAssociations": {"*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook"}`. You're just deleting the `.ipynb` portion.

This should cause VS Code to read/write the notebooks correctly.

Details on the GitHub thread that led me to this solution can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7139).

Comment: My version already has the the version without the .ipynb, but i get the same error.

Comment: I believe this is now `"jupyter-notebook"`

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinstall VSCODE.

In the menu just below your file's tab, click on **...>Export>Python**, this will open another tab that you will be able to save as a .py extension file.